# Node mongodb stores data as string instead of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two same functions, first saves some stuff and also saves ref to productId and second saves another stuff and saves ref to productId too. The problem is first writes ref to poductId as object and everything is ok but second function saves ref as string and in mongodb i see ObjectId but when im trying to display data on screen i cant access into object i have only string with ID of refer. Any ideas?

first model which is ok

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const dishPositionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Products'
    },
    dishId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Dishes'
    },
    weight: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('DishPositions', dishPositionsSchema)
```

and second which stores only strings instead of objects

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const diaryPositionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Products'
    },
    dishId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Dishes'
    },
    weight: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        required: true
    },
    timeOfEatingId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'TimeOfEating'
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('DiaryPositions', diaryPositionsSchema)
```

Comment: Did you take a close look on those two functions? Model is not responsible for saving.

Comment: You said " in MongoDB I see ObjectId" means it is saving it correctly, you just can't access into an object, so if you share your code how you are getting it or accessing it, will make more sense

Answer (score 0):

I know where i did mistake... i didnt write populate('productId')...  everything is fine now thanks!